# What is the runtime complexity of this function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript, time-complexity, big-o

I believe it's quadratic O(n^2) but not 100% sure due to uncertainty of how the `.filter()` and `.map()` operations work in JavaScript.

The big question I have is whether the entire `filter()` operation completes before starting a single `map()` operation, or if it's smart enough to perform the `map()` operation while it's already iterating within the `filter()` operation.

### The method

```
function subscribedListsFromSubscriptions(subscriptions: Subscription[]) {
    return new Set(listSubscriptions.filter((list) => {
        return list.subscribed;
      }).map((list) => {
        return list.list_id;
  }));
}
```

### Example input data

```
let subscriptions = [ {
  list_id: 'abc', 
  subscribed: false
}, {
  list_id: 'ghi',
  subscribed: false
}];
```

### From what I see

It appears to be:

- `filter()` for each element of `subscriptions` - time `n`
- `map()` for each remaining element - time `n` (at maximum)
- `new Set()` for each remaining element - time `n` (at maximum)

For the `new Set()` operation, I'm guessing it's creating a new object and adding each element to the created instance.

If there were many duplicates in data, one might expect the efficiency to increase.  But we don't expect many duplicates in data, and from my understanding of 'Big O', the maximal limit is what's used.

From this analysis, I'm expecting the time complexity to be either `O(n^2)` or `O(n^3)`.  But as stated, I'm unsure of how to interpret it for certain.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is still not very clear how you did come to this and what is the question, but from the provided code the compexity is `O(n)`. Either you forgot to provide some other details or you misunderstand the idea of Big-O notation :)

Comment: Based on your analysis, isn't it `O(2N)` or `O(3N)`, which is then ~ `O(N)`? I'm not sure why you're adding exponents each time there's an iteration.

Comment: your complexity should be `O(n)`. Check it out in this way. Move the argument of the `Set` outside the constructor, and create a temp variable with the `filter` and then the `map`. Then pass this variable inside the `Set` constructor. You can even optimize your code removing the two loops (filter and map) and use a single loop with `reduce` which performs both the operations at the same time

Comment: @FrankModica In the 'analysis' section, I was thinking that the the 'map' operation was being performed inside the 'filter' operation... but as you're pointing this out now, I'm realizing it probably isn't... and it's linear overall, as you're pointing out

Comment: @quirimmo Thanks for the tip on the 'reduce' method... I think i'll switch to that.

Comment: Since it hasn't been spelled out : paralellism doesn't matter for complexity analysis. Even if it helps you reduce `O(2n)` (or any other constant than 2) into `O(n)`, remember that `O(2n)`  is the same order of complexity as  `O(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your interpretation of the order of operations is correct: filter, then map, then create a Set.

However, in order for this algorithm to reach O(n^2), you would have to create a nested loop, for example:

- create the Set for each element of the array
- compare each element witch each other element in the array.

This is not the case here. In the worst case scenario (no duplicates), the algorithm will iterate the input array three times, meaning the O(3*n) complexity which is still linear, not quadratic.